# Excel data validation for Alphanumeric and Special characters

Tags: excel, validation, ms-office, alphanumeric

I'm trying to add Data Validation to 50 cells in a column that will only accept:

1. Alphanumeric
2. Hyphens (dashes)

No restrictions for length.

I did find some examples, but they are all for a single cell. If I try to change it to a range it breaks and won't let me save.

I tried this:
`=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-")))`

Which works for cell A1. However, if I change A1 to anything else - it won't let me even save the formula. And I need a range instead - O2:O50.

Here is how I am trying to do it:

1. Select a range of cells I need apply validation to, which O2:O50
2. Click on Data Validation
3. Select Custom Data validation and enter a formula above into the Formula entry.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand. You apply a Data Validation rule to one cell, then copy that Validation to the other desired cells.

Comment: I do the following:
1. Select a range of cells I need apply validation to: O2:O50
2. Click on Data Validation
3. Select Custom Data validation and enter a formula above into the Custom Validation into the Formula entry.

I will update description, sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: If that's the case, given the formula that you posted (which references cell `A1`), the Data Validation for cell `O5` will be `=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(` **A1** `,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(` **A1** `))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-")))`, that for cell `O6` will be `=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(` **A2** `,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(` **A2** `))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-")))`, etc. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you.

Someone has suggested me a solution that has done what I needed.

It is to select cells I need to apply validation to, in my case O2:O50. Then in validation add this formula:
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(UPPER(O2),SEQUENCE(,LEN(O2)),1),"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-")))

It does exactly what I need

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I wasn't clear enough of where data will be entered actually.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested me an answer on a different website.

1. Select cells I need to apply validation to, in my case O2:O50.
2. Then in validation add this formula:
   `=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(UPPER(O2),SEQUENCE(,LEN(O2)),1),"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKL`

Similar was suggested by the comment above!